# How to remove \ (backslash) from link?

Tags: php, url, backslash

How to remove \ from links I got from scraping.

Example:

```
https:\\/\\/graph.facebook.com\\/v1.0\\/159463177547058\\/photos?fields=source\u00252Cname&limit=100&after=MjA4MTA5NTMyNjgyNDIy
```

Is there any way?

Comment: just search the stackoverflow you can self answer this in couple of minutes

Comment: Its not *scrapped*, its **escaped**.

Comment: Anyway i got the real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try feeding it into `stripslashes()`.

```
$no_slashes_url = stripslashes("https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v1.0\/159463177547058\/photos?fields=source\u00252Cname&limit=100&after=MjA4MTA5NTMyNjgyNDIy");
```

Comment: @HugoRocha no that method does something completely different.

Comment: @Ian okay. I know nothing from PHP. I would use string builder in C#.

Comment: No it does not work. `\u00252` is `%`, but with this function it will simply drop the `\ ` and leave `u00252` as part of the string.

Comment: @Havenard is correct. He got to it before I did, so please see his answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is an escaped sequence where special symbols are replaced by it's escape equivalent.

Usually, you can revert this by using `stripslashes()`. Howover, this escape sequence uses `\u` for UNICODE symbols which is not supported by PHP.

But you can use this little hack instead:

```
$raw = "https:\\/\\/graph.facebook.com\\/v1.0\\/159463177547058\\/photos?fields=source\u00252Cname&limit=100&after=MjA4MTA5NTMyNjgyNDIy";
$url = json_decode('"'.$raw.'"');
```

This function converts UNICODE escaped symbols into it's UTF-8 equivalents. Only because this is an URL we can trust those UNICODE escaped sequences will be safely converted to ASCII without issues, preserving the URL functionality.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (although the upvotes for @Mark's answer are still valid, because in a 'normal' situation that would be the one).

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace()` would be a good place to start

http://pt2.php.net/str_replace

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: Keep in mind that "unescaping" is something completely different to just removing backslashes! Just think of special control characters that will break on str_replace.